# Manual memory management in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting

To the fact that Xcode5 hasn't been officially released but is available as the developer Preview, I may suspect that this question might be rejected or may be closed eventually (to comply with the Non-Disclosure-Agreement)

But still I need to get answer or some kind of clarification on the question regarding to the memory management in Xcode-5.

"Apple has announced they are deprecating manual memory management in Xcode 5" in fact true?
If so when will it be deprecated? Is there any official dates from Apple that by this release non-arc compatible code will break.. ?
Is it something that we can't use non-arc code or we can't use manual memory management while building with Xcode5 & further ..?

Based on the facts only, I can proceed to prioritize my refactoring.

Any expert help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.
Balram

Comment: Whether or not it is true, in Apple stuff, deprecation means you should know they want to get rid of it. When and whether they actually get rid of something deprecated is always subject to change.  If huge swaths of devs are continuing to use it, they'll hold off generally. But to their credit it should be noted that ARC works well, and ultimately reduces their cost of supporting MRC mistakes which can be a lot.

Comment: MRC is not deprecated. Neither is ARC. GC, however, is deprecated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apples product plans.